# I can't send images from js to php

Tags: javascript, php, file, fetch

I'm trying to send images from my form to my php webservice.
For now, I'm just trying to see if i receive it well.

and with this code:

html:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="images" id="images" />
            <button class="bouton" id="valider">envoi</button>
```

Js:

```
const sample_image = document.getElementById('images'); 
const valider = document.getElementById('valider'); 


valider.addEventListener('click', () => {
    upload_image(sample_image.files[0]);
})


const upload_image = (file) => {

    
    const form_data = new FormData();
    
    form_data.append('sample_image', file);
    console.log(form_data);
    fetch(host+"add.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body:form_data
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Php:

```
echo json_encode($_FILES['sample_image']);
```

It's working but only for 1 image, but i need send many.

and when i try to change my JS to :

```
upload_image(sample_image.files);
```

(without the [0])
it's not working.

I just wanted to send an array of files and then use it in my php, but it says

> Notice: Undefined index: sample_image

Does it exists a way to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check whether this is a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Are multiple files sent properly (such that PHP does not handle that properly)?

Comment: I didn't success to find, when i do a console.log(file), i see the array with the multiple images, but when it returns from my PHP, it looks not existing, so i don't know if it s the js who doesn t send it correctly, or the php who don't receive it correctly.

Comment: Why not check your browser's network console for this? Also, if you dump `$_FILES` in PHP, what does that contain?

Comment: it looks being empty in $_FILES, but my js variable is filled

Comment: What about `$_POST['sample_image']`? -- I would at least check....

Comment: no it was not too, the problem was that files didn't went good in form_data, i posted the answer and is now working, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

it's working with :

```
const upload_image = (files) => {

const form_data = new FormData();

let compt = files.length;
for(let i=0;i<compt;i++)
{
    form_data.append('sample_images[]', files[i]);

}
console.log(files.length);
console.log(form_data);
fetch(host+"add.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body:form_data
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}); }
```

thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the FormData to receive an array instead of a single item:

```
const upload_image = (files) => {

const form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('sample_images[]', files);
console.log(form_data);
fetch(host+"add.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body:form_data
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}); }
```

Comment: I tried but i still have the same error